# SQL Select if else

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help.. I need to output the value of `DisplayName` if the value of `fullname` return a null or empty as `FullName`.

something like

```
if(u.first_name && u.last_name are not empty)
    output CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) 
else
    output max(case when t.field_id = 1 then t.value else '' end)
```

but how? also my query took 3.45 seconds :(..

```
SELECT * FROM(  
    SELECT
          t.user_id,
```

> `##this code`
>   max(case when t.field_id = 1 then t.value else '' end) DisplayName,
>   CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) FullName,

```
          max(case when t.field_id = 270 then t.value else '' end) Gender,
          max(case when t.field_id = 274 then t.value else '' end) Birthday,
          max(case when t.field_id = 274 then FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(t.value,'%m/%d/%Y'))/365)  else '' end) Age,
          max(case when t.field_id = 275 then t.value else '' end) Phone,
          max(case when t.field_id = 286 then t.value else '' end) Email,
          max(case when t.field_id = 71 then t.value else '' end) Occupation,
          max(case when t.field_id = 73 then t.value else '' end) CurrentCountry,   
          max(case when t.field_id = 24 then t.value else '' end) Region,   
          max(case when t.field_id = 355 then t.value else '' end) Province,   
          max(case when t.field_id = 354 then t.value else '' end) City  
    FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data t 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
        user_id id,
        max(case when meta_key = 'first_name' then meta_value end) first_name,
        max(case when meta_key = 'last_name' then meta_value end) last_name
        from  wp_usermeta  
        GRoup by user_id

    )as u
    ON u.id = t.user_id  
    GROUP BY user_id
)temp 
WHERE 1 = 1  
##Some Condition to be added 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: CONCAT(IFNULL(u.first_name, ''),' ',IFNULL(u.last_name, '')) FullName,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change to a multiple join to same table repeatedly to get each field on its own criteria 
as a possibility of performance.  Start the profile data one for say the field_id = 1 as the basis,
then join all the rest on that same key, then no grouping by or max/case when on every tested row.
IF some fields may NOT exists, just have as LEFT-JOIN to the re-used table with alternate alias.
I would ensure you have a compound/covering index on your profile table with the following key

( user_id, field_id, value )

Then do the following query.  The interesting thing here, is it basically opens the same table for each "component" part of the user_ID and gets them all lined up, but runs the query based only on a single instance of records associated with field_id = 1 in the where clause.  All the other instances are in their respective aliases joined ON clause.  So now, I just run through the records for field_id = 1, and if found on the other tables, grabs the value, otherwise blank (via coalesce).  Similarly joined to the user meta-data table to get the first/last name parts.

if this works for you, I would be interested in knowing the performance one-way or the other.  The benefit is that it doesn't have to query EVERYONE up front (the inner-most query) to then run the main query of all records, apply the group by, then stop at your 30 limit clause. It just gets up to the first 30 where field_id = 1 and its done.  Now, if the population of "field_id = 1" is a low populated field, and you want to swap with another, so be it, you know your data better than us.

```
SELECT
      DN.User_ID,
      case when fn.user_id is null and ln.user_id is null then DN.value 
           when fn.user_id is null then ln.meta_value
           when ln.user_id is null then fn.meta_value
           else concat( fn.meta_value, ' ', ln.meta_value ) end as FinalName,
      DN.Value DisplayName,
      CONCAT( COALESCE( fn.meta_value, '' ),' ',COALESCE( ln.meta_value, '' )) FullName,
      COALESCE( G.Value, '' ) Gender,
      COALESCE( BD.Value, '' ) Birthday,
      COALESCE( FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE( BD.value,'%m/%d/%Y'))/365), '' ) Age,
      COALESCE( P.Value, '' ) Phone,
      COALESCE( E.Value, '' ) Email,
      COALESCE( O.Value, '' ) Occupation,
      COALESCE( CC.Value, '' ) CurrentCountry,
      COALESCE( R.Value, '' ) Region,
      COALESCE( PR.Value, '' ) Province,
      COALESCE( C.Value, '' ) City
   from
      wp_bp_xprofile_data DN
         LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data G
            ON DN.User_ID = G.User_ID AND G.field_id = 270
         LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data BD
            ON DN.User_ID = BD.User_ID AND BD.field_id = 274
         LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data P
            ON DN.User_ID = P.User_ID AND P.field_id = 275
         LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data E
            ON DN.User_ID = E.User_ID AND E.field_id = 286
         LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data O
            ON DN.User_ID = O.User_ID AND O.field_id = 71
         LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data CC
            ON DN.User_ID = CC.User_ID AND CC.field_id = 73
         LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data R
            ON DN.User_ID = R.User_ID AND R.field_id = 24
         LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data PR
            ON DN.User_ID = PR.User_ID AND PR.field_id = 355
         LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data C
            ON DN.User_ID = C.User_ID AND C.field_id = 354
         LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta FN
            ON DN.User_ID = FN.User_ID AND FN.meta_key = 'first_name'
         LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta LN
            ON DN.User_ID = LN.User_ID AND LN.meta_key = 'last_name'
   where
          DN.field_id = 1
      AND O.Value like '%Programmer%'
   LIMIT 
      0, 30
```

I modified to add a FINAL Name by use of a case/when.
if both the alias FN/LN (first name / last name) are BOTH null, then get the DN (display name) value.  Otherwise we have AT LEAST ONE or BOTH parts of the first/last name field.  If the first name was null, just return the last name.  If the last name was null, return the first name, otherwise BOTH first and last names were available, and return the concatinated version of the name.

As for applying extra WHERE clauses.  As soon as you add a "required" criteria to the where clause against any of the left-join aliases, it will in-effect turn them into INNER JOINs and only include those that HAVE that component AND that component has the value you want... So, per your comment I would just add...

```
   where
      DN.field_id = 1
      AND BD.User_ID IS NOT NULL
      AND STR_TO_DATE( BD.value,'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2009-01-01' and '2012-01-01'
```

You could use your datediff for age and do that between 1 and 2, but just a preference to pick a date range of interest..

For your additional comment about Programmer filtering, the way you had it was trying to test ALL the joined aliases looking for programmer, but at the same time, all of them required because you wanted them all as NOT NULL.  If you want a field required, but no other specific criteria, such as ALWAYS must have email address, then just change

```
LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data E
```

to

```
JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data E
```

if you want to make sure the field is considered only if it has a value other than space (such as your last/first name)

```
   LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta FN
      ON DN.User_ID = FN.User_ID 
      AND FN.meta_key = 'first_name' 
      AND LENGTH( TRIM( COALESCE( FN.meta_Value, '' ))) > 0
```

This will make sure the record is only considered when it actually has a non-empty string value.

Back to your consideration of "%Programmer%'... why would you ever expect a city, Province, region, etc to have a value of programmer.  You should only require the Occupation instance to have the value.  Also, because you had an OR, it was doing ALL the rows.  You would need to have wrapped the conditions something like

```
   where
          DN.field_id = 1
      AND (   O.Value like '%Programmer%'
           OR E.Value like '%@gmail.com'
           OR C.Value like 'Some City' )
```

Notice I wrapped my ADDITIONAL criteria OR components.  This way it still only starts with the Field_ID = 1 entries, but based on the JOIN adds the extra criteria, and in this case, DN.field_id = 1 always, but ANY ONE (or more) of the OR conditions must also be true... The Occupation alias has a value like programmer, email alias has a value of gmail, the city alias like 'Some City'.

Hopefully this clarifies how to implement... Also, make note, that using any LIKE qualifier that has '%' leading the string needs to compare through the whole string and will slow the query down some, but since the join is based on the user ID and the field_ID value, that should still keep it fast (relatively).

Comment: Thanks @DRapp. A big improvement also on the performance. my query finish in 3.45 second while yours finish 0.0184 seconds. I thought too many left join would cause slow down on sql query. by the way the LN.meta_value is always empty. I don't know why.. Fullname return something like `John` only while it should be `John Doe`
Also what if i filter it by age `age between 1 and 2` is this query ok? `SELECT * FROM(another_sqlquery) WHERE age between 1 and 2` or there is a better way for it? Thanks

Comment: also i tried querying `SELECT * From wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'last_name'` and all has a value..

Comment: @Cindy93, revised answer on adding extra "criteria"... As for the last name all having a value, are you considering empty space as valid value, or explicitly NULL for a value.

Comment: @Cindy93, fixed query.. the last name join was falsely using the "FN" alias, not the "LN" alias when I copy/pasted from first name left join instance. Change it and you should be good to go.

Comment: @DRapp.Thanks for everythin... about `last_name` I dont consider empty space as valid value. .

Comment: I see.its much better to put the conditions than using something like `Select * from(sqlquery)`. i tried it and took 2 seconds to finish..Im interested why? :)

Comment: @Cindy93, then you can do something like case when length( trim( ln.meta_value )) > 0 -- same with first name after they have been tested for NULL, or test for NULL OR LENGTH( TRIM( ln.meta_value )) = 0

Comment: @DRapp.. can you help me on something? when i add this `AND  
    (FN.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND FN.meta_value LIKE '%Programmer%') OR  
    (LN.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND LN.meta_value LIKE '%Programmer%') OR 
    (E.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND E.Value LIKE '%Programmer%') OR 
    (O.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND O.Value LIKE '%Programmer%') OR 
    (R.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND R.Value LIKE '%Programmer%') OR
    (PR.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND PR.Value LIKE '%Programmer%') OR
    (C.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND C.Value LIKE '%Programmer%') OR
    (CC.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND CC.Value LIKE '%Programmer%')
`. it mess up

Comment: @Cindy93, see revision on filtering clarification at end of answer area, and updated main query to show filter for programmer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42567/discussion-between-cindy93-and-drapp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT if( trim(CONCAT(first_name,' ', lastName))='', 
           DisplayName, 
           CONCAT(first_name,' ', lastName) ) as Name
     ...rest of the fieds on TA subquery
  FROM (  
    (SELECT
        t.user_id,
        max(case when t.field_id = 1 then t.value else '' end) DisplayName,
        max(case when t.field_id = 270 then t.value else '' end) Gender,
        max(case when t.field_id = 274 then t.value else '' end) Birthday,
        max(case when t.field_id = 274 
           then FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE, 
                          STR_TO_DATE( t.value, '%m/%d/%Y')) / 365)  
           else '' end) Age,
        max(case when t.field_id = 275 then t.value else '' end) Phone,
        max(case when t.field_id = 286 then t.value else '' end) Email,
        max(case when t.field_id = 71 then t.value else '' end) Occupation,
        max(case when t.field_id = 73 then t.value else '' end) CurrentCountry,   
        max(case when t.field_id = 24 then t.value else '' end) Region,   
        max(case when t.field_id = 355 then t.value else '' end) Province,   
        max(case when t.field_id = 354 then t.value else '' end) City  
    FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data t 
    GROUP BY user_id
    ) TA 
    LEFT JOIN 
   (   SELECT  user_id id,
                max(case when meta_key = 'first_name' 
                    then meta_value end) first_name,
                max(case when meta_key = 'last_name' 
                    then meta_value end) last_name
          from  wp_usermeta  
         GRoup by user_id ) as U on (ta.user_id = U.id)
)temp 
WHERE 1 = 1  
##Some Condition to be added 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I did exactly what you want: `if( trim(CONCAT(first_name,' ', LastName))='', DisplayName, CONCAT(first_name,' ', lastName) ) as Name`   See if `trim(CONCAT(first_name,' ', LastName))=''` print display which in the TA subquery is equivalent to the max(case... that you update in your question if it is not empty it will print the concat.